# Read CSV rows into array to display individual rows in different areas of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv

I have been able to successfully read in a CSV file from a URL, parse through it, and write it out to a table. Simple to most but a Herculean effort for me. There is a header row, and each row contains 4 values (the first will be disregarded).

What I need to do is to be able to write each row to a different place on my page at will. I assume to do this I'd need to load each row into a slot in an array, where I can then call them specifically. For example if I want the 3rd entry, and also be able to access each value to build my text string, it would have to look something like:

```
document.getElementById("snow").innerHTML = 'Trail Status: ' + trail[2].status + 'Report Date: ' + trail[2].reportDate;
```

I know that the above code probably is flawed, but it was more illustrative than anything.

What I don't know how to do is setup an array to hold each row (so they can be accessed individually), define each value so it can be a accessed (trail, reportDate,etc), and read the CSV properly into that array.

I'm currently using jQuery and the code below to read, parse, and create the table.

```js
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://data.import.io/extractor/...',
  dataType: 'text',
}).done(successFunction);

function successFunction(data) {
  var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
  var table = '<table>';
  for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
    if (singleRow === 0) {
      table += '<thead>';
      table += '<tr>';
    } else {
      table += '<tr>';
    }
    var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
    for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
      if (singleRow === 0) {
        table += '<th>';
        table += rowCells[rowCell];
        table += '</th>';
      } else {
        table += '<td>';
        table += rowCells[rowCell];
        table += '</td>';
      }
    }
    if (singleRow === 0) {
      table += '</tr>';
      table += '</thead>';
      table += '<tbody>';
    } else {
      table += '</tr>';
    }
  } 
  table += '</tbody>';
  table += '</table>';
  $('body').append(table);
}
```

Any direction to reaching my end state would be greatly appreciated. Ultimately I'm building a dashboard that will show the Trail Conditions (from the CSV) and 10-day weather forecast (from Wunderground) to help plan Snowmobile Trips for local Michigan snowmobilers.

Thanks!
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Create a multidimensional array - with 2 dimensions.  The first index will access each row.  The second index will access each cell within a row.

This reference may help: https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/Array2D.htm

This is an example using your current for loops.

```
function successFunction(data) {
  var parsedData = [];
  var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
  for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
    var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
    for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
      parsedData[singleRow][rowCell] = rowCells[rowCell];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any commas in the CSV data will break this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, i found that PapaParse was the way to go! The data was easy to get at and I had no problems!